# Linked list's data being overwritten

Tags: c

I have a problem in adding data into the linked list. This codes basically is trying to insert new course name into the struct first, then insert the struct into the linked list, and the cycle repeats. The user are responsible to insert the new course name.

The problem now is when user go to the add course operation using scanf, it always overwritten the existing course name in the linked list and add into it.

This is the input and output from the console application:

```
Enter operation: 1
Add Course: asdgvsdrgf
Enter operation: 1
Add Course: ehtyerdc
Enter operation: 1
Add Course: nbcnvbergt
Enter operation: 5    (// Just Print course name in the linked list)
Current enrolments:
nbcnvbergt
nbcnvbergt
nbcnvbergt

Current enrolments:
```

(Changing h files is impossible as it is the requirement of the assignment from university)

**Here are the c and h file attached below:**

bst.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct bstNode {
long student_id;
struct bstNode *left;
struct bstNode *right;
} *BST;
```

courselist.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bst.h"

typedef struct course {
char *name;
BST students;
} Course;

typedef struct courseNode {
Course data;
struct courseNode *next;
} *CourseList;
```

bst.c

```
(not yet written)
```

courselist.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "courselist.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_course_and_num_students(CourseList *self) {
CourseList current = *self;
while (current != NULL) 
{
    printf("%s\n", (current->data).name);
    current = current->next;
}
printf("\n");
}

void insert_course_at_front(CourseList *self, Course data) {
CourseList newNode = (CourseList)malloc(sizeof(struct courseNode));

if (*self == NULL)
{
    *self = newNode;
    (*self)->data = data;
    (*self)->next = NULL;
    return;
}

   newNode->data = data;
   newNode->next = *self;
   *self = newNode;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "courselist.h"
#include "bst.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdbool>

#define MAX_LEN 100

void main()
{   
CourseList my_course = (CourseList)malloc(sizeof(struct courseNode));
my_course = NULL;
Course my_list;
(&my_list)->name = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

bool program_quit = false;
int input_op;

char *insert_course_word;
insert_course_word = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

char *delete_course_word;
delete_course_word = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

do
{
    printf("Enter operation: ");
    scanf("%d", &input_op);

    switch (input_op)
    {
    case 0:            // Quit
        program_quit = true;
        break;

    case 1:            // Add Course
        program_quit = false;
        printf("Add Course: ");
        scanf("%s", (&my_list)->name);

        //(&my_list)->name = (insert_course_word);

        insert_course_at_front(&my_course, my_list);
        break;

    case 2:            // Remove Course
        program_quit = false;
        printf("Remove Course: ");
        scanf("%s", delete_course_word);
        (&my_list)->name = (delete_course_word);
        delete_course(&my_course, my_list);
        break;

    case 3:            // Enrol Student
        program_quit = false;
        break;

    case 4:            // Un-enrol student
        program_quit = false;
        break;

    case 5:            // Print a summary of courses and the number of students enrolled in each course
        program_quit = false;
        printf("Current enrolments:\n");
        print_course_and_num_students(&my_course);
        break;

    case 6:            // Print an ordered list of students enrolled in a course
        program_quit = false;
        break;

    case 7:            // Print a list of courses that a given student is enrolled in
        program_quit = false;
        break;

    default:
        printf("Invalid operation\n");
    }
} while (program_quit == false);

if (my_course != NULL)
{
    destroy(&my_course);
}

//destroy(&my_list);
return;
}
```

Comment: You can remove the special case `if (*self == NULL)` when inserting at the front; the regular code will work for a null head.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem still exist.  

In the main.c, for switch case 1: when user continue to enter new course name, it will just overwrite the previous name and also add the new one in. 

For example: user 1st input: abc123, 2nd input: poiu123. 

However in the linked list it will just show poiu123 and poiu123, which is completely wrong.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to find your problem.

Comment: The problem occurs in `scanf("%s", (&my_list)->name)` when adding another new course.
However I have no clue why it has problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never create a new name, but all course structures' name pointers point to the same memory region, which is the one you are allocating at the start of `main`.

This should do it (waring untested):

```
program_quit = false;
printf("Add Course: ");
char* name = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));   
scanf("%s", name);    
my_list.name=name;
insert_course_at_front(&my_course, my_list);
```

However, I would warn against writing such code in anything related to production code. If the user enters more than 100 characters, you get corrupted memory and if he enters less, you are wasting memory. I think in `C` (i haven#t written production quality c-code in a long long time) you would usually read the input character by character into a local buffer (stopping when either the buffer si full, or you get e.g. a newline) and then allocate a chunk of memory of the appropriate size and finally copy the string to that allocated chunk of memory.

Comment: Yup I agreed you. I need to create the new `my_list` while adding the new course into `my_course`. I am not sure how to do that since I am relatively new to C language particularly data structure.

Comment: @PangYiYang: I have added an untested piece of code, that should do what you want

Comment: Yes your code works! Thanks alot!!! Don't worry about the 100 characters, my assignment stated the I/O restriction that wouldn't have more than 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
typedef struct course {
char *name;
BST students;
} Course;
```

to

```
typedef struct course {
char name[MAX_LEN];
BST students;
} Course;
```

to have some space to place the name

**EDIT - On new info**

```
    Course new_course;
    new_course-> name = malloc(MAX_LEN);

    scanf("%s", new_course->name); // This could be better to prevent buffer overwrite
    insert_course_at_front(&my_course, new_course);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, however I am NOT allowed to change anything from the h files, so it is not an option. (my assignment will be penalised into failure)

Comment: Instead of this `malloc` the string for `name` (I am sorry but my crystal ball is being used by the witch next door)

Comment: The problem of the program is not about the memory management of string (i fixed it with malloc instead of MAX_LEN)


Now in the main.c, for switch case 1: when user continue to enter new course name, it will just overwrite the previous name and also add the new one in. For example: 1st input: abc123, 2nd input: poiu123.

However in the linked list it will just show poiu123 and poiu123.

Comment: .. So what is it about

Comment: I have updated my main.c with your solution, still no luck... =(